# How to open selected file in finder with quik look

Tags: macos, applescript, keyboard-maestro

I am making a script for processing receipts and would like to be able to select a file than trigger a keyboard maestro applescript action that opens the selected file in quicklook than on a different area of the screen run the script below so that the user can input the data while looking at the file

```
display dialog "Date?" default answer ""
set response_date to text returned of result
display dialog "Payee?" default answer ""
set response_payee to text returned of result
set account_choices to {"Bank1", "Bank2", "Cash"}
set response_account to choose from list account_choices with prompt "Select Account:" default items {"Bank1"}
display dialog "Amount?" default answer ""
set response_amount to text returned of result
set filename to response_date & "-" & response_payee & "-" & response_account & "-" & response_amount & ".pdf"
display dialog filename
```

Answer (score 0):

The shell command `qlmanage` with option `-p` followed by your file path activates the Quick Look feature, same as the space bar on the Finder. Example:

```
Set myFile to "/HD/Users/me/Desktop/image.jpg"
do shell script "qlmanage -p " & myFile's quoted form
```

For more options, use Terminal with command: `man qlmanage`

Comment: More recently, `quicklook` is an alias for `qlmanage -p`: `quicklook /path/to/file`